# How to send $get via Post method without including it in a hidden input

Tags: php

Thanks for accepting me in this website, I'm a scripter trying to do things via php.

I got page named `action.php` which it's already in get mode of another page named index.php . So the url is like this `../action.php?id=1` (1 is an example) and  another page named `action1.php`

How can i send the value of the url (1 as an example ) to the another page without using any hidden things?

```
<form action="action1.php" method="post"'>
```

Comment: You should be aware that by using `$_GET`, you are directly exposing you script to user input (which is never a good thing). Might want to store specific data in a php session.

Comment: @alex trax, You can use php super global variables.

Comment: What happens if you add this ID into a hidden field?

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with couple ways;

**$_SESSION**

```
// in form file

$value = $_GET["something"]; // get your GET value

$_SESSION["param"] = $value; // store on session

// in action.php
echo $_SESSION["param"]; // get stored value from session
```

but first, before the use session, you need to start session with `session_start()` method

**$GLOBALS**

```
$GLOBALS['param'] = $value'; 

echo $GLOBALS['param']
```

Comment: `$_SESSION["param"] = (int) $_GET['id'];`

Comment: @Alexander, just an another option